# To use unicode or not in web development project using flask and sqlalchemy

Tags: unicode, python-3.x, flask-sqlalchemy

I am working on a web development project using flask and sqlalchemy orm. My post is related to use of unicode in developing this app. 
What I have understood till now about unicode :

1. If I want my webapp to handle data in languages other than English I need to use unicode data type for my variables. Because string variables can't handle unicode data.
2. I use some database which stores unicode data or take responsibility to convert unicode to raw while saving and vice versa while retrieving. Sqlalchemy gives me option to set automatic conversion both ways, so that I dont have to worry about them.
3. I am using python2.7 so I have to be aware of processing unicode data properly. Normal string operations on unicode data maybe buggy.

Correct me if any of the above assumption is wrong.

Now my doubts or questions :

1. If I dont use unicodes now then will I have some problems if I or flask people decide to port to python3?
2. I dont want to hassle with the thought of my webapp catering to different languages right now. I just want to concentrate on first creating the app. Can I do that later without using unicode right now?
3. If I use unicode now then how it affects my code. Do I replace every string input and output with unicode or what?
4. Conversion of unicode when saving to database, Can it be source of performance problems?

Basically I am asking whether to use unicode or not with explaining my needs and requirement out of the project.

Comment: This article is a good read if you want to understand what unicode is: http://www.joelonsoftware.com/articles/Unicode.html

Comment: thnx for the link. it was good info .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. No, but make sure you separate binary data from text data. That makes it easier to port.
2. It's easier to use Unicode from the start, but of course you can postpone it. But it's really not very difficult.
3. You replace everything that should be text data with Unicode, yes.
4. Only of you make loads of conversions of really massive amounts of text.

Comment: Do i need to put 'u' prefix in every string or only those which have some special character?

Comment: @codecool: You put the u-prefix it on all strings that should be Unicode, which means, all strings meant to contain text designed for humans. For Web that means anything that will end up as HTML. Everything that should be outputted as HTML should therefore be prefixed with u''.

Comment: There is even better solution in many cases. At the beginning of your python file add: from __future__ import unicode_literas, from  now on every string will be on default a unicode unless you explicitly state otherwise